# Count list in columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

fellow Pytoneers or Pythonistas,

I am hoping I can get your help on this issue:

I have more than one pandas data frames that contain as in the example below:

[image]

I would like to create a function that will count values from a list e.g. [a,b,c] and iterate through the columns and the data frames. I would like to return the total number of items found in the columns from the list. I wrote this code, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Could you please help? Thank you in advance for your answers. PS: As I am new to this, my karma is quite low  :D

```
list_of_dataframes = [k,p,r]

list_of_chars = ["a","b","c"]

for dataframe in list_of_dataframes:
        for values in list_of_chars:
            for columns in dataframe:
                count = 0
                if dataframe.columns.str.contains(list_of_chars):
                    dataframe['Total']=count+1
                else dataframe['Total']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join strings columns together and then count values by [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) with joined values together and replaced missing values by empty string. Because there are some values of list with regex characters is necessary escape them by `re.escape` first:

In your solution:

```
k = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2, 3], 
                   'String1':['a d d','a','s'],
                   'String2':['a','a b b','c']})
 
p = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2, 3], 
                   'String1':['c','b','c'],
                   'String2':['a b','a c','d a']})
 
r = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2, 3], 
                   'String1':['a','c d as','c a d'],
                   'String2':['a b c c','a b c','d a b f']})
 
list_of_dataframes = [k,p,r]
```

---

```
import re

list_of_chars = ["a","b","c"]
pat = '|'.join(['({})'.format(re.escape(c)) for c in list_of_chars])

for i, dataframe in enumerate(list_of_dataframes):
    dataframe['Total'] = dataframe.select_dtypes(object).fillna('').agg(''.join, 1).str.count(pat)
    list_of_dataframes[i] = dataframe
     
print (list_of_dataframes)
[   ID String1 String2  Total
0   1   a d d       a      2
1   2       a   a b b      4
2   3       s       c      1,    ID String1 String2  Total
0   1       c     a b      3
1   2       b     a c      3
2   3       c     d a      2,    ID String1  String2  Total
0   1       a  a b c c      5
1   2  c d as    a b c      5
2   3   c a d  d a b f      4]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jezrael. I will look into your suggestion :D

Comment: @Qthry - Do you think `missing values` are blank data?

Comment: @Qthry - added some sample data and solution working correctly

Comment: haha, you were quick! Yes, missing values are black data. I am new to this and sometimes is difficult to understand, please bear with me. Let's suppose I concatenate all the strings into a column, I can't figure out where to refer to that column in the code you posted.

Comment: @Qthry - If select all columns with strings by `dataframe.select_dtypes(object)`, then repalce missing values by `.fillna('')` then `.agg(''.join, 1)` returned new column (Series) with joined values.

Comment: I am getting this error saying: `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 5`

Comment: @Qthry - it is regex error, what is values in list?

Comment: My char list is something like this `list_nonesense = ["none", "?","any","blank","Don’t know","Don’t recall","don't know","Na","None","Ugg","unk","Unknown"]`